# Get first match from or regex group

Tags: c#, re2

I'm trying to build regex expression that will match any  protocol in URL

```
(?:https?|ftp|\w{2,7})://
```

But I want that if 'http','https','ftp' present, it will take them, and not the longest match, like:

```
"hdhttp://"
```

I'm using re2, so I can't look ahead or look behind

Comment: The regex engine will search from left to right and try the alternations. If one matches it is satisfied. But in .NET regex there is the [`RightToLeft` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(VS.85).aspx) available which would match from right to left. [See this demo at regexstorm](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%7Cftp%7C%5Cw%7B2%2C7%7D%29%3A%2F%2F&i=hdhttp%3A%2F%2F&o=r&s=9). If you change input in demo also set the start position to string length.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Yes, it is a cute approach, just RE2 does not support this option. :(

Answer (score 1):

**RE2-specific answer**:

Since in RE2 you cannot use lookarounds, you have to split the pattern and use two. One would be `(https?|ftp)://` and if it does not find the match, use `\w{2,7}://`. Or, use your regex and then check if the match contains `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://` and if yes, and the length of the matched value is bigger than these strings, you need to use these values rather than the matches.

**.NET-related answer**

You may use a negative lookahead to restrict the more generic alternative:

```
(?:https?|ftp|(?!\w*(?:https?|ftp):)\w{2,7})://
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hY0feW/1)

The `(?!\w*(?:https?|ftp):)` negative lookahead will fail the match if the `\w{2,7}` matches a substring that is 2 to 7 word chars and ends with `http`, `https` or `ftp` (add more if you need) right before a `:`.

In .NET, you may also use a negative lookbehind for this (it supports unknown width patterns there):

```
(?:https?|ftp|\w{2,7}(?<!https?|ftp))://
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%7Cftp%7C%5Cw%7B2%2C7%7D%28%3F%3C!https%3F%7Cftp%29%29%3A%2F%2F&i=hdhttp%3A%2F%2F)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using re2 (without look ahead and look behind)

Comment: In C#, re2? Sorry, then you just have to switch to .NET regex.

Comment: It is much faster then .Net regex. Even if I will filter the results after in the code, but I fought that must be a better way

Comment: What good is speed, when you lose the functionality you need? With re2, you would have to spell out all possible match variations with negated bracket expressions. It is impractical. Just discard the regex then, use simple string methods, they are faster. OR you might split the regex in 2. One would be `(https?|ftp)://` and if it does not find the match, use `\w{2,7}://`

Comment: if the regex class is instantiated for a one off regex or reinstantiated instead of reuse, you might get decreased performance. If used multiple times on after creation you get better performance

Comment: In my case, the regex will be created just once and will be run on 250 GB of data, so I am worrying about the performance

Comment: In that case, I'd be more worried about how these data are processed, you are definitely not going to read it in as a single string anyway :)

Comment: In a buffer (byte[]) of 100mb at the time